# Cannot update Entry fields

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to automatically populate Entry fields based on a list, but I'm coming up fairly short.

```
populate = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]

A1 = StringVar()
A2 = StringVar()
A3 = StringVar()
A4 = StringVar()
A5 = StringVar()
A6 = StringVar()
A7 = StringVar()
A8 = StringVar()
A9 = StringVar()
A10 = StringVar()
UN = StringVar()

lfAB1 = Labelframe(frameNewEntry, text = 'Answer 1')
lfAB1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = W+E+N+S)
AB1 = Entry(lfAB1, textvariable=A1)
AB1.pack()

#repeat for AB2 -> AB10

A1.set(populate[0])
A2.set(populate[1])
A3.set(populate[2])
A4.set(populate[3])
A5.set(populate[4])
A6.set(populate[5])
A7.set(populate[6])
A8.set(populate[7])
A9.set(populate[8])
A10.set(populate[9])
UN.set(populate[10])
```

This fails to set the Entry fields to the required data.
However, if I make an error like so:

```
...
A9.set(populate[9])
UN.insert(0, populate[10])
```

The fields fill fine, except obviously for the one with the error. (I know insert() should be used on the Entry field itself but it was very early in the morning!)
It should be note that using insert() to populate the Entry fields doesn't work either.

Any ideas please? :D

Comment: What? Why aren't you using lists for this?

Comment: Are you aware you don't needto use `StringVars`? Would you be satisfied with a solution that doesn't use them at all?

Comment: jonrsharpe, terribly sorry; how could I use lists to achieve what I'd like to?


@BryanOakley, I'd prefer to use StringVars because I can then read any changes made to the input - if there's a method by which I can do that without StringVars I'd be glad to hear it!

For reference, [I'm attempting to have this populated](http://i.imgur.com/yPeefdX.png) with values from a previously-submitted form of the same kind.

Comment: Rather than having separate names for the `StringVar` and `Entry` instances, just have a list of them.

Comment: Yes, you can get the values without using `StringVar` instances. The entry widget has a `get` method exactly for that purpose.

Comment: Ah fantastic, this is working as intended now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a `StringVar` for each entry, because the entry widget has a `get` method for retrieving the current value. You *can* use a `StringVar`, but in my opinion it adds overhead without providing any extra value (unless you use variable traces, which you are not).

For example, assuming your entry widgets are stored in a list, you can print them out easily:

```
def dump():
    for e in entries:
        print("=>" + e.get())
```

You can also create these widgets in a list, which makes your code considerably shorter and easier to maintain:

```
entries = []
for row, ch in enumerate(populate):
    lf = LabelFrame(frameNewEntry, text="Answer %s" % row)
    lf.grid(row=row, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W+E+N+S)
    e = Entry(lf)
    entries.append(e)
    e.pack()
```